How to serialize Powershell Script Output in Rust
I want to return output from powershell script in JSON format. Script.ps1 just returns Get-WinUserLanguageList.

Powershell script library: https://crates.io/crates/powershell_script
#[tauri::command]
fn get_keyboard_list() {
  let create_shortcut = include_str!("script.ps1");
  match powershell_script::run(create_shortcut) {
    Ok(output) => {
      println!("{}", output);
    }

    Err(e) => {
      println!("{e}");
    }
  }
}


I commend to your attention Microsoft Learn on ConvertTo-JSON

"Script.ps1 just returns Get-WinUserLanguageList" - it's a bit hard to tell whether you can meaningfully do anything about that without knowing the contents of script.ps1...

script.ps (not a proper extension) creates a shortcut on in the Desktop directory. How does that produce a language list?

Can you share the contents of the script, the output it's currently printing, and what you want it to print instead? Or if you don't want to print it, what you want it to do instead?

$Test=Get-WinUserLanguageList return $Test
